# Big Sur or newer: proper method to launch apps at boot?

Tags: macos, boot, launchd

I've found some older Q&A such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/101480/how-do-i-start-programs-automatically-when-mac-os-x-boots-up-specifically-vmwar) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256362/how-do-i-launch-an-app-at-boot-startup-on-sierra) discussing setting up a Launch Agent to start an app prior to login.  What are the latest preferred directories and rules/guidelines for setting up the necessary file(s)?

If it helps, I want to have USBOverdrive running prior to login so my pointing device buttons work properly.